# removeFirstPrepend alternative in ibatis to mybatis migration

Tags: migration, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to migrate my application from ibatis to mybatis

i was using removeFirstPrepend="true" keyword in ibatis, but not sure what to use alternative to this in mybatis

any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct replacement - and that is a good thing IMHO because "removeFirstPrepend" was hard to understand.

In MyBatis there are new dynamic SQL tags that are better.  For example:

```
<where>
  <forEach collection="ids" item="id">
    or id = #{id}
  </forEach>
</where>
```

The `<where>` tag is smart enough to write the word "where" at the beginning, and not write the first "and" or "or".  This this could generate a clause that looks like "where id = ? or id = ? or id = ?".

Similarly, the `<set>` tag will write "set" and not write the first ",".

Both of these are specializations of the `<trim>` tag.  With that tag you can specify a prefix and/or suffix to write, and prefix/suffix strings that should be ignored for the first/last item in a list.

So I suppose that `<trim>` is the closet thing to a replacement for "removeFirstPrepend". Personally, I find it much easier to understand.